# How can i make it so when I go into edit mode the mesh stays deformed by armature

Tags: rigging, armature

So when I give a mesh and armature and then deform the mesh in pose mode, when i go into edit mode the mesh gos back to its default position, and for some reason i cant figure out how to make it stay deformed as i go into edit mode

Answer (score 0):

Enable this, almost every modifier has this I believe.

[image]

Comment: you also need to activate the last one on the right. There is still a problem in my opinion, the 3d widget stick to its initial position

Comment: Oh I see thanks!, it's not something I use very often.